# Play one sound on shake

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio

I made an application to play sound while i shake my phone.
The problem is that i don't know how to play the sound only one time,
because it plays the sound multiple times.

There is no errors in my project.

Here is the code of my activity:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private SensorManager mySensorManager;

private float xAccel;
private float yAccel;
private float zAccel;
private float xPreviousAccel;
private float yPreviousAccel;
private float zPreviousAccel;

private boolean firstUpdate = true;
private boolean shakeInitiated = false;
private final float shakeThreshold = 5f;

private final SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se){
        updateAccelParameters(se.values[0], se.values[1], se.values[2]);
        if((!shakeInitiated) && isAccelerationChanged()){
            shakeInitiated = true;
        } else if ((shakeInitiated) && isAccelerationChanged()){
            executeShakeAction();
        } else if ((shakeInitiated) && !isAccelerationChanged()){
            shakeInitiated = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

private void updateAccelParameters(float xNew, float yNew, float zNew){
    if (firstUpdate){
        xPreviousAccel = xNew;
        yPreviousAccel = yNew;
        zPreviousAccel = zNew;
        firstUpdate = false;
    } else {
        xPreviousAccel = xAccel;
        yPreviousAccel = yAccel;
        zPreviousAccel = zAccel;
    }
    xAccel = xNew;
    yAccel = yNew;
    zAccel = zNew;
}

private boolean isAccelerationChanged(){
    float deltaX = Math.abs(xPreviousAccel - xAccel);
    float deltaY = Math.abs(yPreviousAccel - yAccel);
    float deltaZ = Math.abs(zPreviousAccel - zAccel);
    return (deltaX > shakeThreshold && deltaY > shakeThreshold)
            || (deltaX > shakeThreshold && deltaZ > shakeThreshold)
            || (deltaY > shakeThreshold && deltaZ > shakeThreshold);
}

private void executeShakeAction(){
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whopa);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whopa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    player.start();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener,
            mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have to pause the accelerometer change checks while the music is playing, afterwards you can continue to check if the accelerometer has changed.

Comment: Detect when the user starts and stops shaking the device, and use some sort of timer to prevent another sound from being played until X ms have passed since the user stopped shaking the device.

Comment: It's hard to pause accelerometer while sound is playing because sound i 3 second's long